# Add nbsp; in php

Tags: php

I have this

```
            $output .= '<li class="'. $term->slug .'"><a href="'. $term_link .'"><span>'. » . $term->name .'</span></a></li>';
```

How can I add a non-breaking space between the » and the term name?

Comment: `<span>&raquo;&nbsp;'.$term->name .'</span>` rtm: [strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```html
<?php
$output .= "<li class='". $term->slug ."'><a href='". $term_link ."'><span> &nbsp; » &nbsp; ".$term->name."</span></a></li>";
?>
```